# How to have powershell display the current directory

Tags: powershell, anaconda, conda

I recently ran "conda init powershell" on my powershell in order to be able to activate conda environments (previously, "activate env_name" would not work).
However, I do not like what this has done to my powershell. For one, it always displays the current virual environment even if it is simply the base environment. Also, it no longer displays the current directory I am in.

I tried running commands like conda deinit, but it does not exist.
I tried removing anaconda from the path and restart the computer, but it did not work and powershell still recognized conda as a cmdlet.
I tried changing defaults from powershell, but it only lets me change Options, Font, Layout, and Colors. None of which are helpful.

Minimal reproducible example. With "pathtoanaconda/Scripts" in path, open PS and run "conda init powershell", restart powershell.

Notice in my screenshot how my current directory is not displayed.. Instead, I get a "(base) PS" for any directory I am in[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF6bd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. I quickly realized https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-the-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the has instructions that solve my problem.

I had to delete the information on that file in order to undo the conda init.